# Datagridview returning your own value

Tags: datagridview, controls

I have a custom control datagridview.

In my control, I want to return cell value in my own

Standart way:
GridValue = Datagridview1.rows(0).cells(1).value

Goal  :
GridValue = Datagridview1.rows(0).cells(1).Myvalue

This method or property or etc. is written in the custom datagridview

Is It possible to do so ?

So far, I have walked around methods,properties and dealt with accesbible objects a bit. The editor hasn't approved any of them.

I use winforms but the others lang. are also would be helpfull

Thank you

Comment: Without asking WHY you need to do this and before you jump down this rabbit hole, I would point out that creating a custom `DataGridView` to accomplish this will be tricky since the `DataGridView` may contain many cells. How is the `DataGridView` going to keep track of all the extra “MyValue” variables for EACH cell in the `DataGridView`?

Comment: The `DataGridView` has multiple rows and columns, at the intersection of a single row and column is a `DataGridViewCell`. From what is posted, it appears you may want to create a “custom” (inherited) `DataGridViewCell` with this extra “MyValue” property. This will most likely lead to creating a “custom” `DataGridViewColumn` that uses your “custom” `DataGridViewCell`. Again, this is just something to consider since it is unclear why you need a cell to contain two different values.

Comment: Thank you for not asking about the need :)

Comment: I'm trying to reduce code size that I'have to write ahead . MyValue is actually not a second value for each cell, it's fed on the actual value and it makes some translations when it is called. For example, cell datatype integer but value is dbnull.value.To avoid type error, "MyValue" will check the type and the actual value and if its integer and dbnull, it will return zero value instead. Why I don't sort it out with a function and I insist on the cell.value pattern is the practice on writing.

Comment: Now you have me confused… your comment is difficult to understand: _”For example, cell datatype integer but value is dbnull.value. To avoid type error, "MyValue" will check the type and the actual value and if its integer and dbnull, it will return zero value instead”_... first, the cell CANNOT be both an integer AND dbnull. The cell will either, have a value or it will be null. There is no other possibility.

Comment: The “MyValue” variable you describe appears unnecessary, if it is being used to check to see if the “Value” in a particular cell is a valid integer… then simply check it, I see no need to introduce another variable for this.

Comment: Have you looked at the `int.TryParse(string stringNum, out returnedValue)` method? This method will return true if the given string is a valid integer. It will ALSO return the same valid integer value. You could use this to check the cells value by sending a string version of the cells value to the `int.TryParse` method.

Comment: Put this in an “if” statement knowing that if the try parse method returns “true”… you have a VALID integer and that value is returned in the “out” variable. If it returns “false” it is either null or not a valid string integer value and the returned out variable will be zero (0). NOTE: No exceptions will be thrown if the string passed to the `TryParse` method is null or if it is simply a string of characters.

Comment: English is not my native language and that causes dark points sometimes. Sorry about that. if Im not wrong DbNull.value is possible in an integer cell if the grid is datatable  fed and data comes from server. Null value also part of the problem. I have already a method to check if value is valid Which I've seen the logic in Ms Acces and copied.  User can enter value or skip the column. I want to skip the control part and put it to the server with its value or zero if its null. When the variable meets the cell.value, exception occurs  in null scenario.

Comment: This is for just faster and readable coding.Im not stuck with the topic in my project. Thank you again

Comment: For clarity and your comment… _”if Im not wrong DbNull.value is possible in an integer cell if the grid is datatable fed and data comes from server.”_... I must differ. Regardless of the “type” of the cell (int, double, string… etc), it either has a value or is null. It makes no difference what “Type” the cell is… it either contains a value (which could be an empty string) or it is null… the cells value cannot be both. I will conclude this unproductive back and forth and hope you get it working. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for the effort. In case someone needs, the answer is extension methods.